# How to convert a list with strings into a 2D list

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

`list = ['aa#1#ll', 'bb#2#ff', 'cc#3#ff']`

I want to convert it to a 2D list in this format

`list2 = [['aa', '1', 'll'], ['bb', '2', 'ff'], ['cc', '3', 'ff']]`

How can I do this in Python 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Python's [`split(delimiter)`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) method inside a generator:

```
list2 = [x.split("#") for x in list]
```

**Explanation:** Here, for each string `x` in the original list, we are calling `x.split("#")` on it, which will give a list of substrings that are separated by hashes in `x`, and we are adding the result to the list `list2`.

Comment: Well explained and clean syntaxe